# WSO2 EI - retry, suspend - still wait for TimeOut

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-esb

can anybody explain me how to enable correct retry?
I use only Integration Studio Editor just downloaded from WSO2 site.

I have code with URL `https://api.github.com/user` that return 401 and JSON (see logs). So why WSO2 wait for TimeOut that is set in configuratipon file (I have changes it to 30 seconds)? Shouldn't retry immadietly after getting 401 or after time in `<timeout><duration>`?

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy name="HelloWorld" startOnLoad="true" transports="http https" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="true"/>
            <property action="remove" name="NO_ENTITY_BODY" scope="axis2"/>
            <property name="NO_KEEPALIVE" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="true"/>
            <send>
                <endpoint name="github">
                    <address format="get" optimize="mtom" uri="https://api.github.com/user">
                        <timeout>
                            <duration>5</duration>
                            <responseAction>fault</responseAction>
                        </timeout>
                        <suspendOnFailure>
                            <initialDuration>1000</initialDuration>
                            <progressionFactor>2.0</progressionFactor>
                        </suspendOnFailure>
                        <markForSuspension>
                            <retriesBeforeSuspension>3</retriesBeforeSuspension>
                            <retryDelay>1000</retryDelay>
                        </markForSuspension>
                    </address>
                </endpoint>
            </send>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <log level="full"/>
            <log level="custom">
                <property expression="$axis2:HTTP_SC" name="###### HTTP Status #######" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
            </log>
            <respond/>
        </outSequence>
        <faultSequence/>
    </target>
</proxy>
```

WSO2 logs:

```sh
    [2020-06-14 14:51:57,811]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.SourceHandler} - Writer null when calling informWriterError
[2020-06-14 14:51:57,812]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.SourceHandler} - Connection time out after request is read: http-incoming-4 Socket Timeout : 30000 Remote Address : /127.0.0.1:55124
[2020-06-14 14:51:58,149]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.endpoints.EndpointContext} - Endpoint : github with address https://api.github.com/user currently TIMEOUT will now be marked active since it processed its last message
[2020-06-14 14:51:58,150]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} - To: http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous, WSAction: , SOAPAction: , MessageID: urn:uuid:76137204-8644-4e3c-a1ba-4e1f011382ea, Direction: response, Payload: {"message":"Requires authentication","documentation_url":"https://developer.github.com/v3/users/#get-the-authenticated-user"}
[2020-06-14 14:51:58,151]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} - ###### HTTP Status ####### = 401
[2020-06-14 14:52:27,843]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.SourceHandler} - Writer null when calling informWriterError
[2020-06-14 14:52:27,844]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.SourceHandler} - Connection time out after request is read: http-incoming-5 Socket Timeout : 30000 Remote Address : /127.0.0.1:55145
[2020-06-14 14:52:28,341]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} - To: http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous, WSAction: , SOAPAction: , MessageID: urn:uuid:35dda6ba-faae-47bd-8180-d130a1604877, Direction: response, Payload: {"message":"Requires authentication","documentation_url":"https://developer.github.com/v3/users/#get-the-authenticated-user"}
[2020-06-14 14:52:28,343]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} - ###### HTTP Status ####### = 401
[2020-06-14 14:52:57,868]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.SourceHandler} - Writer null when calling informWriterError
[2020-06-14 14:52:57,869]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.SourceHandler} - Connection time out after request is read: http-incoming-6 Socket Timeout : 30000 Remote Address : /127.0.0.1:55164
```

How to make it working?

Answer (score 3):

Can you try like below with the address endpoint instead of http.

```
<endpoint>
<address uri="http://localhost:8000">
  <suspendOnFailure>
     <initialDuration>1000</initialDuration>
     <progressionFactor>2.0</progressionFactor>
  </suspendOnFailure>
  <markForSuspension>
     <retriesBeforeSuspension>3</retriesBeforeSuspension>
     <retryDelay>1000</retryDelay>
  </markForSuspension>
  <timeout>
     <duration>6000</duration>
     <responseAction>fault</responseAction>
  </timeout>
</address></endpoint>
```